# Having issues with Gateway Access URLs(token issues) in wso2 API Manager 4.1.0

Tags: wso2, access-token, wso2-api-manager

Recently we have configured latest WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0 and brought up the service, however we are seeing an error while hitting the token url

curl https://testapi-am.example.com:8243/token
{"code":"404","type":"Status report","message":"Not Found","description":"The requested resource is not available."}

This was working on the prior version i.e wso2 API Manager 3.1.0.

On the wso2 API Manager 3.1.0 version we are not facing any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In APIM v4.x versions token API and other key management APIs are not exposed via the gateway. Instead you have to call https://testapi-am.example.com:9443/oauth2/token

Comment: for below pizzashack api also we are seeing same response , please let me know the url what to use.
curl https://testapi-am.example.com:8243/pizzashack/1.0.0/menu
{"code":"404","type":"Status report","message":"Not Found","description":"The requested resource is not available."}

Comment: For API you have to use the above url. Did you deploy the API? Is this a single node setup?

Comment: its a single node setup only , but we are getting above same 404 code with the mentioned url

#curl testapi-am.example.com:8243/pizzashack/1.0.0/menu 

{"code":"404","type":"Status report","message":"Not Found","description":"The requested resource is not available."}

Comment: Can you create a new revision and deploy the API?

Comment: Getting same response even after created a new revision of api and deploy

~]# curl https://testapi-am.helixreach.com:8243/pizzashack/2.0/menu
{"code":"404","type":"Status report","message":"Not Found","description":"The requested resource is not available."}

Comment: Do you see any errors in the carbon log? Is it same if you deploy a new API?

Comment: Don't see any errors in carbon log while deploying but when i tryout the api  method in devportal getting below response

Comment: TID: [-1234] [] [2022-11-17 22:29:24,194]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = /pizzashack/1.0.0/menu, HEALTH CHECK URL = /pizzashack/1.0.0/menu
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-11-18 05:17:43,700]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = /pizzashack/2.0/menu, HEALTH CHECK URL = /pizzashack/2.0/menu